# Css Float Position

Tags: css, css-float

I have a section on my homepage which displays an excerpt of the latest posts, and I've create some css for the first 2 post for them to be side by side, but I can't get the second article to float next to the first article. Even if I enter float:right on the second title, it floats to the right , but under the first one. You can see exactly what I mean if you visit my site www.ehowtodrywall.com. How do I get the second title to float to the right of the first title in the latest article section  ...

Answer (score 2):

You have `clear:both` on `div.srp-widget-singlepost`.
If you remove that, they will all float next to each other.

When you clear a float, it's starting that type of float over "on a new line".
It's like you're hitting a "carriage return" on that kind of float.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the width of the floats is greater than the width of their parent. You need to decrease their width if you want them next to each other, say 50% 50%. But don't forget that margin and borders add on to the width.

Comment: See I thought that might be the problem, so I made the div really small, like 300px each, and the parent div is 1250px, and I still get the same results, the div is put under the top one ... I don't understand what I'm doing wrong ...

Comment: You are sure there is no margin or borders or padding on either `<div>' and that they are both floated and you have no `clear` rules (like `clear: left;`)?

Comment: There is margins added, but they are only 5 px on each side, and I never used the clear:left rule since I don't really know what it does ... I have put float:left on both the divs ... it should work ... but its not and this is why I'm looking for answeres here ...